# Is is possible to create a SUBSET-SUM instance that each subset is "unique"?

Tags: subset-sum

Given a SUBSET-SUM instance $S$ with a weight $W$, is it possible to create, in polynomial time, a new non-empty instance $T$ (at most the same length as $S$) with weight $M$, that for each non-empty subset of set $T$ and its sum $s$, it has a unique $(s-M)^2$, and that a subset of $T$ adds up to $M$ iff a subset of $S$ adds up to $W$?

Comment: Is $M$ an input or an output?  Can it be freely chosen by the algorithm?

Comment: If there exists such a reduction, then the variant of subset sum problem where each subset has a unique sum would be NP-complete. Unfortunately, [no one has proved or disproved it](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42502/subset-sum-problem-with-at-most-one-solution-for-any-target).

Comment: @D.W. It's an output, it only depends on $S$ and $W$.

Comment: @xskxzr I edited it, so it may be easier to prove (or disprove).